# Creating a 2D-Array Field in an Ada Tagged Type

Tags: arrays, record, ada

I'm trying to create a Java/C class equivalent in Ada. From what I've researched -- the equivalent would be a Tagged Record. I'm wanting to create a field that is a 2D Array, however with the code below -- it gives me the following errors.

Code:

```
package Foo is
type Bar is tagged
    record
        field1 : Integer;
        field2 : Integer;
        type field3 is array (1 .. 10, 1 .. 5) of Integer;
    end record;
end Foo;
```

Error:

```
foo.ads:6:25: missing "end record;" for "record" at line 8

foo.ads:7:17: no "record" for this "end record"
```

This tells me that "Anonymous arrays are not allowed as components".

```
package Foo is
type Bar is tagged
    record
        field1 : Integer;
        field2 : Integer;
        field3 : array (1 .. 10, 1 .. 5) of Integer;
    end record;
end Foo;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your second version fails is that

```
field3 : array (1 .. 10, 1 .. 5) of Integer;
```

declares a new, unnamed (anonymous), type (`array (1 .. 10, 1 .. 5) of Integer`), and you’re not allowed to nest type declarations.

Depending on your application, you might try

```
type Twod_Array is array (Integer range <>, Integer range <>) of Integer;
type Bar is tagged
   record
      field1 : Integer;
      field2 : Integer;
      field3 : Twod_Array (1 .. 10, 1 .. 5);
   end record;
```

or

```
type Twod_Array is array (Positive range <>, Positive range <>) of Integer;
type Bar (First, Second : Natural) is tagged
   record
      field1 : Integer;
      field2 : Integer;
      field3 : Twod_Array (1 .. First, 1 .. Second);
   end record;
```

[Hmm. I said `First, Second : Natural` to allow for zero-length arrays. But I’m not sure what the point of `A_Bar : Bar (0, 10);` would be!]

Answer (score 2):

You attempt to declare one named type inside the declaration of another named type.  You can't do that.

Also, Ada does not allow record fields of anonymous types, so you have to ensure that you have declared all the types you need for the fields of your record, before the declaration of the record itself.

Are you sure you need values in the range `-32_768 .. 32_767` (that's all Ada promises about the type `Integer`)?  Normally one would declare a type matching the requirements of the problem.  (Of course, if the problem is to match the C type `int` closely, then one should use `Interfaces.C.int`.)

Comment: How do I go about declaring an array as a field then? And no, I probably don't -- but that's a smaller issue I'll address when I start cleaning my program up.

Comment: In the end I want to create tagged record ("class") that has 2 integer fields and an array field.